# Pythonic way to modify all items in a list, and save list to .txt file

Tags: python, file, list

I have a list of strings.

```
theList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to add integers to the strings, resulting in an output like this:

```
newList = ['a0', 'b0', 'c0', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'a3', 'b3', 'c3']
```

I want to save this to a .txt file, in this format:

```
a0
b0
c0
a1
b1
c1
a2
b2
c2
a3
b3
c3
```

The attempt:

```
theList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
newList = []

for num in range(4):
    stringNum = str(num)
    for letter in theList:
        newList.append(entry+stringNum)

with open('myFile.txt', 'w') as f:
    print>>f, newList
```

Right now I can save to the file myFile.txt but the text in the file reads:

```
['a0', 'b0', 'c0', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'a3', 'b3', 'c3']
```

Any tips on more pythonic ways to achieve my goal are very welcome,

Comment: Answerers, note that the OP has asked for "more Pythonic" solution, not shorter or more complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of your last line, use:

```
f.write("\n".join(newList))
```

This will write the strings in newList, separated by newlines, to f.  Note that if you don't actually need newList, you can combine your two loops and write the strings as you go:

```
the_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

with open('myFile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for num in range(4):
        for letter in the_list:
            f.write("%s%s\n" % (letter, num))
```

Comment: nice .. and favor `xrange` over `range` in general (though with such small numbers it shouldn't really matter)

Comment: It's better to use `range` in answers on this site because it is compatible with python 3.

Comment: @jamylak Can you tell that I still code with 2.6/7 .. thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I don't understand. I mean it's better for people viewing the answer who may be using python 2.x or python 3.x so it will work for them either way.

Comment: @jamylak I wasn't disagreeing with you

Comment: @jamylak Yup, I was offering an explanation for my original comment and thanking you for your comment. It's all good.

Comment: Thanks very much :D This seems like just what I was after. Must remember % !

Answer (score 2):

This would probably do your job

```
with open('myFile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for row in itertools.product(range(len(theList)+1),theList):
        f.write("{1}{0}\n".format(*row))
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm unfamiliar with itertools

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compress your code a little bit you can do:

```
>>> n = 4
>>> the_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> new_list = [x+str(y) for x in the_list for y in range(n)]
>>> with open('myFile.txt', 'w') as f:
...     f.write("\n".join(new_list))
```

Comment: I think this is actually *less* Pythonic than the OP's solution: 1) it uses `map` and `lambda`, which aren't as Python as list comprehensions or straight `list.append`, 2) map+lambda+itertools is more complex and probably slower than just the KISS solution, making it less Zen of Python-ish, 3) it doesn't use the `with` statement, so the file may not be closed (though in CPython it is), 4) it's better to compress your code using gzip. :-)

Comment: I don't think that this very readable (Simple is better than complex) though at some level pretty cool to squeeze all of this into this short code.

Comment: I know, since I stared learning haskell my code is getting uglier and uglier. Urgh.

Comment: I didn't know you could have for loops on one line like that, that is pretty compressed!

Comment: Although, for the output I'm after I have to reverse the order of the `for` loops :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is fine -- one of the points in the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is "simple is better than complex". You could easily rewrite this as a one-liner (possibly using a nested list comprehension), but what you have is fine and easy to understand.

But there are a few minor changes I might make:

- Often it's better to use a more portable serialization in your text file, like JSON, via Python's `json.dump(newList, f)`. Good for using the `with` statement, though.
- You don't need a separate `stringNum` variable -- `str(num)` inside the append is just as good
- Follow [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming conventions, so `new_list` instead of `newList`
- Nitpicking: Your question title says "modify all items in a list", when in actual fact your code is building a new list. Usually this is the Pythonic thing to do anyway -- side effects like modifying the list in-place are often less useful.

Comment: Looked up JSON and reading through the PEP-8 conventions.
Inside the append- thanks (quite an obvious one now I see it :D)
You're right, I set out intending to modify the list, but in my code I created a new one. It does seem like a better idea too. Thanks